# Informatica Expression Transformation

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have an Input port in expression transformation which is *middle name* field with datatype as `string(10)`. I am using some data quality checks on it and `o/p port` is having dataype as `char(1)`.

So for eg: If *middle name* is `KUMAR`, It should pass only `K` in *output port* as I have selected datatype as `STRING(1)` in O/P port.

But I see, It is **not getting truncated** and `KUMAR` is passing through in data. But if I use a *variable port* in the same expression and give it as `STRING(1)` and use value received from *Variable port* in *another output port*, I see only `K` letter going through in data.

Why is this happening?

Comment: There is something you've missed e.g. maybe you set the scale of the port to 1 instead of the precision, what you've described doesn't fit with the numerous truncation errors I've seen. Even assuming what you've described was true, when the output port feeds the value to the next string 1 input port it would truncate there

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be very direct requirement. Please use the substr fn as below

substr(middlename,1,1).

Take this value as the o/p port. I hope this should help.